# How do I uninstall Bitdefender Endpoint Security for Mac?

Tags: macos, anti-virus

This application is not listed in my apps, nor does it ship with an uninstaller I can locate. The support site says to contact their support team, but the product is not listed in the drop down for support requests.

Here's what I tried so far in order to get it to stop running, so I could safely delete the program from disk, but it didn't help:

1. sudo ps aux | grep -i endpoint
2. sudo launchctl list | grep -i bitdefender
3. for each bitdefender product listed: sudo launchctl remove
4. reboot

The application ran again after reboot.

Answer (score 9):

I might be a bit late on this one, but the uninstall script is one of

```
/Library/Bitdefender/AVP/Uninstaller/BitdefenderforMacUninstaller.app
/Library/Bitdefender/AVP/Uninstaller/EndpointSecurityforMacUninstaller.app
```

There should be a shortcut in the applications folder too.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you have multiple Bitdefender products installed and you only want to remove one of them, this is not the right approach.

1. finder go to /Library/StartupItems, then delete Bitdefender folder
2. finder go to /Library/LaunchDaemons, then delete com.bitdefender.* items
3. finder go to /Library/LaunchAgents, then delete com.bitdefender.* items
4. sudo ps aux | grep -i endpoint, note process pid
5. sudo kill -9
6. reboot

The program no longer launches after reboot. Now clean up its files from disk:

1. sudo rm -rf /Applications/Bitdefender

Comment: You're supposed to do it from your UTM dashboard, btw, that's what it's for. The consumer products should have an uninstaller & a user dashboard at the Sophos web site. The corporate version is all handled from the UTM.

Answer (score 2):

This method only works if you startup disk is **not** encrypted:

- Restart your Mac and hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during boot to go into recovery mode
- In the menu bar choose `Utilities` > `Terminal`

Execute in the terminal:

```
cd /Volumes/[Your-Mac-HD-Name]
cd Library/
rm -f LaunchAgents/com.bitdefender.*
rm -f LaunchDaemons/com.bitdefender.*
rm -rf Bitdefender
```

- Reboot your Mac